# After installing shinyapps and shiny, RUN and SOURCE botton disappeared, how to get them back?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I'm using R 3.2 and Rstudio 0.98.953

Just installed shinyapps and shiny, and the RUN APP button showed up (some people say it will only appear in preview version of Rstudio 0.99)

But the RUN and SOURCE botton disappeared. Any way I can get them back? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is the currently open file a file in a Shiny app? If RStudio detects that you're in a Shiny app (the file you're viewing is `ui.R` or `server.R` or `app.R` etc.) then it automatically lets you run the shiny app instead of "run the code" because that's the correct thing to do. When you switch to a different file that's outside of a shiny folder, it should go back to normal.

If you're not inside a Shiny app and it's showing "Run App", then you should file a bug with RStudio

Comment: But is there a shortcut to run an R script with `shiny` library with the `source()` function, not with `runApp()`? `runApp()` does not work completely as I wish it to do.